# Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"markUp"

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver

Code :

```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\pkshirs3\\SeleniumMaterial\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
    String urlToBeUsed = "internalURL";

    webDriver.get(urlToBeUsed);

    Thread.sleep(3000);
         webDriver.findElement(By.name("markUp")).sendKeys("456");
```

HTML code :

```
<input id="markUpPairNumberField-inputEl" type="text" name="markUp" style="text-align: right; width: 100%;" class="x-form-field x-form-text x-form-focus x-field-form-focus x-field-default-form-focus" autocomplete="off" aria-invalid="false" data-errorqtip="">
```

Whats the issue ?

Comment: Strongly suspect the get is failing.

Answer (score 0):

By.name - this method will give you the element if your tag is input and has 
          correct name, like "markUp". Also, try to debug if that element is 
          loaded in the dom at the time you are trying to crawl the page.

For other tags you can refer this official documentation - http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp